# PerfMon discrepancy - "Bytes in all Heaps" memory does not equal gen0 + gen1 + gen2 + LOH

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, perfmon

Ran perfmon and added counter ".net CLR Memory" and thought I saw a figure discrepancy.

Shouldn't "bytes in all heaps" be gen0+gen1+gen2+LOH?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx) :)

"Bytes in all Heaps" is just gen1 + gen2 + the LOH.